# Using only JQuery to update Twitter (OAuth)

Tags: jquery, json, twitter

we would like to send a JSON update command to twitter, but only using JQuery, not having to go to the webserver and have it done in PHP.

The thing I can't grasp really is how to send the user credentials in the JQuery/JSON twitter API call. Our user credentials are from Twitter's OAuth.

thanks, cheers!

Comment: What's wrong with doing it with a server-side language?

Comment: there's nothing wrong with it, and we have it working for a bunch of other operations. I just feel it's more secure using 100% jquery. Having a php script that updates twitter can be exploited, as it holds the auth information for all the users of my system. If the solution is 100% client browser, there's no exploitation possible, as only the user has access to its oauth credentials (which live in their browser's javasript). Know what I mean?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

If you did this, you would have to embed your application's Key, **Secret (!)**, and the user's token into the webpage (which is then exposed to the user). I don't think this is a good idea. (And the risk of compromise is the same.)

This might be the thinking of most other people - however there is a [Javascript OAuth library](http://oauth.googlecode.com/svn/code/javascript/). But it's not inteded for the use inside websites (cross-domain ajax limitation) but rather for other JS platforms (like Chrome/Jetpack plugins or Vista Sidebar widgets).

Comment: yes you're right. Forgot we need to sign and encrypt the Twitter API request with our application's key. There's no way I would expose this key in our webpage.

Comment: What about mobile apps inside a webview, the user will never have access to the source …

Answer (score 2):

Iam not 100% sure, but i think you need an serverside script to authenticate with twitter.

check out this link:

[Jitter](http://code.google.com/p/jquery-jitter/)

its an api implementation for Jquery and Twitter (but altough has an PHP Script to handle some things.)

Comment: Good solution! Having a PHP script that returns OAuth tokens. As these tokens only work when called from our domain (as it is the one registered with Twitter) it's 100% secure. The PHP doesn't update anything and the JQuery only works when hosted on our domain.

Answer (score 0):

Just pasting some answers I've found researching the same question:

As for rate limits (which is why I came here):

> [Official Twitter answer:](https://dev.twitter.com/discussions/5025)
>   @episod Taylor Singletary
>
> The REST API (api.twitter.com/1/*) accepts authentication for every
>   method. When you use authentication, it's pulled from the user's rate
>   limit.
>
> The Search API, which is rate limited totally differently than the
>   REST API, doesn't use OAuth or any form of authorization. This is
>   where you'd likely want to use vanilla JSON-P requests.
>
> Just because an OAuth signed request returns data, doesn't mean the
>   request was valid OAuth. In contexts where we can consider an invalid
>   request as an unauthenticated request instead, we'll service it.  19
>   weeks 1 day ago reply

Another Twitter [answer](https://dev.twitter.com/discussions/8471) regarding jQuery and security.

As for Jitter, I think it's dead.