# jQuery plugin to post updates on Twitter?

Tags: jquery, twitter

Is there a plugin for jQuery to post a update on Twitter that uses Twitter OAuth?

And if possible I would like a `Hello World` example.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Using only JQuery to update Twitter (OAuth)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1769713/using-only-jquery-to-update-twitter-oauth)