# Chestnut: Using OAuth'd jQuery to interact with Twitter

Tags: php, jquery, twitter, oauth

Disclaimer: There are similar questions [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6700106/twitter-oauth-authentication-in-javascript) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1769713/using-only-jquery-to-update-twitter-oauth), but they've not been resolved.

From what I understand, it shoud be possible to do a server-side (php) OAuth, and then use a my-website-only-valid access token to interact with Twitter? (A token which is thus not dangerous to reveal.)

I wonder if this is still possible, of if Twitter has changed since then?  I need full interaction with twitter for my webapp, but the 350 connections/hour/IP limit that Twitter sets will not be enough, which is why I need the connections to go client-side.

There was apparently something called [Jitter](http://www.ohloh.net/p/jquery-jitter) that implemented this, but the project seems dead and the author to have vanished.

Does Twitter simply want to block this type of access (webapps)?  Or am I missing something?

Any help is much appreciated!